# Firebase Notifications failure

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently I purchased the apple developer account. I had to change my bundle Id within my xcode project. But ever since my notifications are not working. I have checked the logs within firebase and I receive this error

```
Successfully sent message: { results: [ { error: [Object] } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 1,
  successCount: 0,
  multicastId: 7533609589421548000 }
```

I know the error must have something to do with my bundle Id changing but I can't figure out a solutions. Thanks so much to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: I‘m not a 100% sure, but I assume that all previously registered device tokens are assigned to your previous app and must re-register with the new one.

Comment: I save the FCM token into my database on signup. Do you suggest just creating a new user do can these new fcm tokens? @jeromegamez

Comment: Did you upload push certificate to firebase ?

Comment: If you try creating a new user with your „new“ app (=app with the changed bundle I’d) and if you can send a notification to them, this would be an indication that my theory could be correct, but again, I‘m not sure ^^